# update UILabel from UIDatePicker in tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uidatepicker

I'm building a static tableview with one cell containing a label and another a UIDatePicker. I want to update the label with the date from the date picker but the text in the label will not update. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

My code so far looks like this:

```
class HomeController: UIViewController {

    let tableView: UITableView = UITableView()

    private var showDatePicker: Bool = false

    var dateLabel = "Select date"
    var datePicker = UIDatePicker()



extension HomeController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @objc func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let formatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .short

        let selectedDate = formatter.string(from: sender.date)
        dateLabel = selectedDate
        print("The selected date is: \(selectedDate)")
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let dateCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: dateId, for: indexPath) as! DateCell
            dateCell.homeController = self
            dateCell.dateTextLabel.text = dateLabel
            return dateCell

        case 1:
            let datePickerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: datePickerId, for: indexPath) as! DatePickerCell
            datePickerCell.homeController = self

            datePicker = datePickerCell.datePicker
            datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
            return datePickerCell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            toggleShowDatePicker(tableView)
            datePickerChanged(sender: datePicker)
        }
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
    }

    private func toggleShowDatePicker(_ tableView: UITableView) {
        showDatePicker = !showDatePicker
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `tableView.reloadData()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your `datePickerChanged` method you need to tell the table view to reload the first cell.

You can reload the whole tableview with `tableView.reloadData()` but you should just reload the one cell. Do that with the following line:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)
```

Make that the last line of your `datePickerChanged` method.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked when I put it in the DidSelectRowAt method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload your tableview after updated your label value. Please replace this method

```
@objc func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let formatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .short

    let selectedDate = formatter.string(from: sender.date)
    dateLabel = selectedDate
    tableView.reloadData()
    print("The selected date is: \(selectedDate)")
}
```